# Как отправить значения чекбокса на сервер через ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Как передать значение чекбокса?
Когда мне нужно отправить число я делаю это вот так:

HTML:

```
  <form method="post" id="height_form" action="#">
 <input class="opts_headlines" type="text"  id="height_opt" name="length" value="15">
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#btn_refresh").click(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: 'generator/generator.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#height_form").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
          return false; 
      });
    });
```

PHP:

```
$data = $_POST['length'];
    $length =$data;
    $log = $length === null;    
    if ($log) {
        $length = 15;
    }
```

А как передать значение `true` - если чекбокс checked, и `false` если нет

Comment: А какая разница? установите любое значение в value, если выбрали чекбокс - то получите это значение в php, если значение пустое, значит не выбрали данный чекбокс

Comment: Передать _**PHP**_-значения `true/false` вы никак не сможете, по крайней мере в рамках `x-www-form-urlencoded` запроса, к-ый вы используете. Но я сомневаюсь вам так уж необходимы именно _**PHP**_-ные значения типа `bool`, их вполне можно заменить текстовыми эквивалентами, приводимыми к `bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если checkbox `checked`, то в запросе он будет, если нет - то его не будет. Соответственно в php проверка будет примерно следующего вида:

```
<?php
$example_checked = isset($_POST['example-checked']);
```

В примере ниже, сделал вывод в консоль, чтобы можно было увидеть, что "уходит"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn_refresh").click(function() {
    var formData = $('#height_form').serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'generator/generator.php',
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="height_form" class="container" method="post">
  <input id="height_opt" class="form-control" type="text" name="length" value="15">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
    <input id="checkbox" name="expample-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true">
  </div>
  <button
    id="btn_refresh"
    class="btn btn-primary"
  >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

решил задачу вот так

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      $("#btn_refresh").click(function(){
              var l_password = false;
              if ($('#item_opt_light').prop('checked'))
                {
                    l_password = 'light_password_checked="on"';
                }
              var length = $("#height_form").serialize();
              var data = length+"&"+l_password;
              console.log(data);
          $.ajax({
            url: 'generator/generator.php',
            type: "POST",
            data:data ,
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
          return false; 
      });
    });
```

php

```
$light_password_checked = isset($_POST['light_password_checked']);
```

Comment: задавайте вопрос корректнее, т.к. не все поняли что чекбокс нужно передать за пределами `<form>`. Не понятно зачем вам это нужно, не проще ли его оставить в `<form>`?

Comment: @programmer403 честно говоря я не знаю в чем разница, через форму я передаю числовое значение